# Java multithreading error correction - threadsafe singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

*FIRST OFF: Yes, I know that the best way in general to do singletons in Java is with `enum`s, but if for some reason you need to subclass a singleton class, you can't use enums, so...*

David Geary at JavaWorld published an article a long time ago on implementing singletons in Java.  He argued that the following optimization to a thread-safe singleton implementation is problematic:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() 
{ 
    if (singleton == null) 
    { 
       synchronized(Singleton.class) 
       { 
           if(singleton == null) {
              singleton = new Singleton();
           } 
       }
    }
    return singleton; 
}
```

(See more at: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html?page=4#sthash.G8lzWOfT.dpuf)

Geary says that this 'double-checked locking' optimization

> is not guaranteed to work because the compiler is free to assign a
>   value to the singleton member variable before the singleton's
>   constructor is called. If that happens, Thread 1 can be preempted
>   after the singleton reference has been assigned, but before the
>   singleton is initialized, so Thread 2 can return a reference to an
>   uninitialized singleton instance.

My question: Is the following change going to fix that problem or not?  I've started reading Goetz's Java concurrency book and it seems that the compiler is allowed to shuffle within-thread operations, so I am not quite confident...Still, it seems to me that `singleton = temp;` is an atomic operation, in which case I think it should.  Please explain.

```
public static Singleton getInstance() 
{ 
    if (singleton == null) 
    { 
       synchronized(Singleton.class) 
       { 
           if(singleton == null) {
              Singleton temp = new Singleton();
              singleton = temp;
           } 
       }
    }
    return singleton; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code is sequentially consistent with the first code (they are strictly equivalent in a single threaded environment) and does not introduce any additional memory synchronisation points.

So yes, a compiler is authorised to rewrite the second code and turn it into the first one which means it is unsafe too.

The fact that `singleton = temp;` is atomic doesn't help here. It only means that singleton is either null or holds the same reference as temp. But that does not preclude temp/singleton from pointing to a "non-constructed" object.

The Java Memory Model works in terms of happens-before (HB) relationships. In both codes there is only one hb: the exit of the synchronized block hb a subsequent entry into that block. `if (singleton == null)` does not share any hb relationship with `singleton=…` so the reordering can happen.

The bottom line is that the only way to fix it is to introduce a hb between the two statements: by moving the if inside the synchronized block or by marking singleton volatile for example.

Comment: A follow-up question: 'The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration' says *If Helper is an immutable object, such that all of the fields of Helper are final, then double-checked locking will work without having to use volatile fields.*  But that doesn't seem to mesh with the 'JSR 133 (Java Memory Model) FAQ' re: construction of objects with final fields -- namely, won't DCL and JMM allow the object to published before the correct field values are necessarily visible, even if all the field values are final? I don't think I understand the semantics of final.

Comment: If you don't publish a reference to the object before the end of its constructor (no escape of this) and all its fields are final then you have the guarantee that the object will be properly constructed. You can refer to the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: So: if the constructor finishes in Thread A, without synchronization an arbitrary Thread B can still see stale versions of any non-final fields in A--in other words, constructors are just like other methods in that respect.  The 'constructor finishing' establishes a HB relationship between the final-field-write of the Thread A and later final-field-reads of any other threads -- but not for other fields.  Right?

Comment: Yes that's about it. Note that because it can happen (to read stale values of non final fields) it is unlikely to happen in practice as most compilers will apply a memory barrier at the end of a constructor that writes final fields, effectively publishing final and non final fields together. But this is not required by the memory model and therefore not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on optimization which can be applied for the second code by compiler (it means that second one can be transformed to first one by compiler). You can write the code using AtomicReference which will allow to avoid the problem:

```
private static AtomicReference<Singleton> singleton = new AtomicReference<Singleton>(null);
...
public static Singleton getInstance() 
{ 
    if (singleton.get() == null) 
    { 
       synchronized(Singleton.class) 
       { 
           if(singleton.get() == null) {
              singleton.compareAndSet(null, new Singleton());
           } 
       }
   }
   return singleton.get(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleted as wrong, keeping the empty answer for its discussions. Wow, live and learn!

Comment: The quote agrees with the very people who have designed and implemented the language so I would tend to trust them... Many weird/broken things can happen when more than one thread is involved.

Comment: While David Geary, without a doubt, is a rockstar-level developer and carries a lot of creditbility, I am unaware of his role in designing and implementing the language, and his bio does not say anything about it either: http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/conference/speaker/david_geary    Why, has he worked for Sun?

Comment: I was talking about Goetz/Lea who have written more or less the same thing about that exact pattern in the past.

Comment: Hmm... I'll look into it some more. If nothing else, should not `singleton` field be `volatile`?

Comment: If it is volatile then, indeed, there is no problem any more.

Comment: See for example: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Ouch! Deleting my answer. Learned something new.

Comment: If volatile is the answer, why the long article? Why not just say, "use volatile variables"?

Comment: It explains why the code can break if you don't use volatile, which is not necessarily intuitive. And using volatile does imply a slight performance hit which is why people are (wrongly in this case) tempted not to use it.